# How to first try to find and then check if an element exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running the following but it is giving all the lists:

```
if($($wikiDOM.find('.infobox .location').length )) {
  $("#results").append("<li>" + $wikiDOM.find('.infobox .location').text() + "</li>");
}

United States
undefined
United States
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

I'd only need the ones with a location not undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I did see few answers, I am not sure if the issue is that in my case I first need to `.find` then check if it exists and I am doing it wrong, as you can see on my code I am using `length` as they suggest

Comment: @CommercialSuicide changed the question title to make it more unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($($wikiDOM.find('.infobox .location').length )) {
```

should be

```
if($wikiDOM.find('.infobox .location').length) {
```

(no need to push that length-value into a jquery-object)